# htaccess RewriteRule avoid loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Website can have links like: `website.com/url`; `website.com/en/url`; `website.com/de/url`.
I'm trying to redirect all queries without language tag to the specific page by this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/en/(.*)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/de/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page/$1 [L]
```

But get a redirect loop for the root page. I can just exclude home page like this

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$`

But I want to know, what I'm doing wrong, is it a way to avoid the loop in this case for home page too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(?:en|de|page)/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* page/$0 [L]
```

Importantly you need to add `/page/` in exclude list as your rule is rewriting to `/page/`.

Comment: right now for testing purposes whole .htaccess is only your code.

Comment: Is it redirect error or 500 internal error due to infinite looping (btw this rule works on my apache)

Comment: I see this in my browser: ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `page/` directory as well? If not then it must be a cache issue. Try testing in a new browser.